# android repeat sound lag

Tags: android, audio

I am working on a application in which i have to play a horn sound and i am having a sound clip of it. Now i want to play this sound file in a loop but i am getting a second lag once its repeat the same file. I am using media player class to play the sound.

Please let me know how i can remove this lag to play a sound file without a lag.

```
     final MediaPlayer mp_horn1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.horn_wf);
  mp_start.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp_start.start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Naqi if you want to make sound repeat you have to wait until your first sound completes. Check this [url](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html)

Comment: i can wait but dont wait any lag between that.

Answer (score 0):

Hey use this code for play sound in loop.

```
  final MediaPlayer mp_horn1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.horn_wf);
   mp_start.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp_horn1..setLooping(true);
            mp_start.start();
        }
    });
```

You have to use this - .setLooping(true);

Hope this will work. All the best.